# Parse error syntax error unexpected t_string

Tags: php, wp-enqueue-style

I'm getting the following error:

> PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'qtip'
>   (T_STRING), expecting ')' in your code on line 14

in this code:

```
<?php
// Always use wp_enqueue_scripts action hook to both enqueue and register scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_and_register_qtip_scripts_and_style' );

function enqueue_and_register_qtip_scripts_and_style(){

    // Use `get_stylesheet_directoy_uri() if your script is inside your theme or child theme.
    wp_register_style( 'qtip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/jquery.qtip.min.css', 'all' );
    wp_register_script( 'imagesloaded', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/imagesloaded.pkg.min.js', true );    
    wp_register_script( 'qtip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/jquery.qtip.min.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded'), false, true );
    wp_register_script( 'tooltip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/tooltip.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded', 'jquery-qtip-min), false, true );

// Add the styles first, in the <head> (last parameter false, true = bottom of page!)
   wp_enqueue_style( 'qtip', null, false, false );

// Using imagesLoaded? Do this.
wp_enqueue_script( 'imagesloaded', null, false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'qtip', false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'tooltip', false, true );
}
?>
```

The 14 line says: `wp_enqueue_style( 'qtip', null, false, false );`

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm very new to coding so thank you for the tip Pieter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot a apostrophe after `'jquery-qtip-min)`

```
wp_register_script( 'tooltip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/tooltip.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded', 'jquery-qtip-min), false, true );
```

should be

```
wp_register_script( 'tooltip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/qtip-js/tooltip.js', array('jquery', 'imagesloaded', 'jquery-qtip-min'), false, true );
```

I know that sometimes you can look over such things, especially if (maybe) you aren't an experienced coder, but still please try harder next time to spot such really simple typos before posting questions on WPSE.